# java swing border, using 2 or more colors

Tags: java, swing, colors, border

Hi im trying to create a border that has top and left as black and bottom and right as grey.
does anyone know if this is possible and how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
new CompoundBorder(
    BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 0, 0, Color.BLACK),
    BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 1, Color.GRAY)));
```